# Український відповідник до каучсерфінгу та каучсерфера

Tags: переклад, відповідник

У статті про явище каучсерфінгу вжито кілька варіантів перекладу, в тому числі і спроба знайти відповідник - "гостьовий туризм", хоч це, мабуть, не переклад, а спроба визначення.

> Що таке **каучсерфінг**? **Гостьовий туризм** – це шикарна альтернатива нудним
>   готелям і галасливим хостелам. Суть його в тому, що ви можете
>   ненадовго «вписатись» у місцевого жителя. Гостинні хости пропонують
>   мандрівникам ліжко або навіть кімнату у своїй квартирі зовсім
>   безкоштовно. Цим вони дають змогу зануритись у культурний простір
>   країни зі сторони місцевого жителя.
>
> Громада каучсерферів дуже велика, і умовно ділиться на три «табори»
>   залежно від можливостей:
>
> Хости – це ті, хто пропонує зупинитись у себе. Серфери – ті, хто
>   шукають собі вписку. Люди, котрі залюбки познайомлять вас з містом,
>   але з певних причин не можуть запропонувати житло. [джерело](http://1001idea.info/scho-take-kauchserfinh-7-vidpovidej-ta-porad-mandrivnyku/)

там-таки вжито слово в формі варваризма:

> Варто пам’ятати, що **couchsurfing** – це не база безкоштовного житла, а
>   місце інтернаціонального знайомства. Тож тут категорично не
>   приймається нахабство і «нахлібництво».

Чи є українські слова, які позначали б це явище і називали б зайнятих цим осіб?

Comment: Саме явище відносно нове, тому і термін варто новий придумати.

Answer (score 1):

[Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kauchserfing) пропонує варіант "софання", яке, напевно, утворене від слів "[софа](http://sum.in.ua/s/sofa)" + "[шукання](http://sum.in.ua/s/shukannja)", що може бути непоганим відповідником, адже з англійської "couch" - це диван, а "surfing" можна перекласти як "пошук".

Також там є варіант "диваношукач" як відповідник до слова "каучсерфер", що також може стати хорошою альтернативою.